# updateGZ3D.sh fails silently if grunt CLI is not installed globally,

Tags: installation

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It should be added to the [instructions for gzweb JavaScript development](http://gazebosim.org/gzweb#development-collapse-0) that the `grunt CLI` has to be installed globally, otherwise the `gzweb/updateGZ3D.sh` will fail silently. Just the `npm install` command alone is not enough.

This is how to install the grunt command line interface globally:

> npm install -g grunt-cli

Afterwards, grunt will actually build the project.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12478/updategz3d.sh-fails-silently-if-grunt-cli-is-not-installed-globally,/) by [suzanak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2430/suzanak/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The page you linked pulls its contents from [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gzweb_development&cat=gzweb) tutorial. You could make a pull request to the [gazebo_tutorials](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/src) repository suggesting the change.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0